# Multipart fileupload from Node.js server to PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, file-upload

I am using Node.js to simulate a `Multipart/form-data` upload POST to a php script.

I am using the [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) Node.js package to simulate the post, as they have mentioned in their documentation.
Here is the Node.js code.

```
var request = require('request');
// var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');

var formData = {
  // Pass a simple key-value pair 
  "my_field": 'my_value',
  // Pass data via Buffers 
  "my_buffer": new Buffer([1, 2, 3]),
  // Pass data via Streams 
  "my_file": fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/pic.jpg')
};

request.post({url:'http://127.0.0.1/speedtest/php/receiver.php', formData: formData}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
  // console.log(httpResponse);
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

The PHP Script is:

```
<?php
echo "post ".json_encode($_POST);
echo "\n get ".json_encode($_GET);
echo "\n request ". json_encode($_REQUEST);
echo "\n file ".json_encode($_FILES);
?>
```

The response the I get on executing the Node.js script is:

> Upload successful!  Server responded with: post []  get []  request []
>   file []

Why is PHP not detecting the request variables in the backend?

Comment: I just tested this code as is, changing only the `url:'http://127.0.0.1/speedtest/php/receiver.php'` and it works fine for me. I get full JSON populated post data echo response as expected. only the `get` is empty.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII What do u think the issue here might be? Any settings that I need to turn on or something?

Comment: no idea, but I upvoted your question

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Thanks, I hope someone comes up with an Answer. I can't find anything that works.